# Dashed Tubes in 3D

Tags: graphics3d

Is it possible to easily make "dashed" tubes?  In two dimensions I can easily dash lines,

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image: dashed line]

I'd like the same effect, but in three dimensions.
Start with a tube (potentially not just given by points, but by a `BSplineCurve` or `BezierCurve`,

```
Graphics3D[{
   Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}],
   Tube[BezierCurve[{{0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}]],
   Tube[BSplineCurve[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1/2}, {1, 1, 1}}]]
   }]
```

[image: solid tubes]

Is it possible to use some styling or graphics directive to cause the tubes to be broken up into smooth, regularly-shaped, little pieces?  Inserting `Dashed`, eg. `Graphics3D[{Dashed, ...`, doesn't work.

If not, what is a good solution for achieving such an effect?  Supporting `Dotted`, `DotDashed`, `Dashing` and `Tube`'s `CapForm` for the segments would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define functions:

```
bsf1 = BezierFunction[{{0, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}];
bsf2 = BezierFunction[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1/2}, {1, 1, 1}}];
```

then trace them with gaps with small `Tube` or `Cylinder`:

```
ln1 = Tube[#, .01] & /@ Partition[Table[bsf1[n], {n, 0, 1, .01}], 2][[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]];
ln2 = Tube[#, .01] & /@ Partition[Table[bsf2[n], {n, 0, 1, .03}], 2][[1 ;; -1 ;; 1]];

Graphics3D[{Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}], ln1, ln2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Vitaliy's answer can easily be adapted into exactly what I'm looking for.  Here's the code I wound up with in the end:

```
(* The user can just pass a list:*)
dashedTube[on_, off_, OptionsPattern[Tube]][func_List, radius_: 0.01, each___] := 
    dashedTube[on, off][BSplineFunction[func, SplineDegree -> 1], radius, each]

(* or a BSpline/BezierFunction: *)
dashedTube[on_, off_, OptionsPattern[Tube]][func_, radius_: 0.01,  each___] := 
    Tube[#[[All, 2]], radius, each,
        If[OptionValue[VertexColors] === Automatic, 
           VertexColors -> Automatic, 
           VertexColors -> (Blend[OptionValue[VertexColors], #] & /@ #[[All,1]])]
    ] & /@ Partition[{#, func[#]} & /@ Union@Clip[
  FoldList[Plus, 0, {on, off}[[1 + 
      Mod[Range[0, Ceiling[2/(on + off)]], 2]]]], {0, 1}], 2]
```

Now, using `bsf1` and `bsf2` from Vitaliy's answer,

```
Graphics3D[{
    CapForm["Round"],
    dashedTube[0.05, 0.03, VertexColors -> {Red, Green}][ bsf1, 0.02],
    dashedTube[0.1, 0.02][{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 0.015, VertexColors -> {Blue, Purple}],
    CapForm["Square"],
    dashedTube[0.03, 0.03][bsf2, 0.02, VertexColors -> {Red, Green}]
}]
```

The `each` optional variable applies style to each individual dash, while the options in the curried head apply to the whole string.

[image: dashing tubes]